# Issue with awk statement while passing condition statement

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to count the null records of a column in a file, subject to a condition. But the condition is not working.

- Example input: fixed width file,

```
                 761128424607/22/20197611284246CAD052020DHH 0073578EKLAVY3
ELEKBAFXXL7900271761128424406/22/20197611284244CAD042020DKA 0038244EDITTU8                     
                 761128424606/22/20197611284246CAD052020DHH 0073578EKLAVY3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ELEKBAFXXL7900271761128424406/22/20197611284244CAD042020DKA 0038244EDITTU8
```

- code

  ```
  RE='[[:space:]]{17}' awk -v m=1 -v p=17 -v r='&& substr($0,28,2)==06'
      $'BEGIN{re = ENVIRON["RE"]}{c = substr($0,m,p)}  c ~ "^(" re ")$" r  {N++}  END {print N+0}' <  input_file.txt
  ```
- Desired output: `1`, since 2 records having null in file and out of this 1 record satisfies condition `substr($0,28,2)==06`
- Actual output: `0`, which is wrong

Comment: @rowboat its zero sorry . i am editing the question. Basically i am looking for a flexibility to pass conditions to awk statement. is there a way to do this. This issue occurs only for fixed width. for the delimited records i have got correct. I am pasting the same logic for delimited version.

Comment: delimited file logic for finding nulls count subject to a logic:     -  thres=$( RE="$col_null_patt" awk -F "$sep" -v  n="$col_pos" -v r="$col_cond"  'BEGIN {m = ENVIRON["RE"]} NR>1 &&  $n ~ "^" m "$" r {N++} END{print N+0}' "$cp_input")

Comment: @rowboat GNU Awk 4.0.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Do the massive chains of blanks at the end of your sample input really exist in your data? Is it important for them to exist in the example in your question? If the answer to either question is "no" then please [edit] your question to remove them.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to construct an awk script from the values of some shell variables.   In that case, construct the entire script as a shell variable and then run it.   e.g. `awkscript="......";    awk "$awkscript"`.    BTW, programs that generate code which is later executed are not unusual, but they do require even more care and attention to detail than usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do what you're asking for by letting the contents of the shell variable `r` expand to become part of the awk script before `awk` gets called to interpret it but there's almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you're really trying to do:

```
$ r='&& substr($0,28,2)=="06"'
$ RE='[[:space:]]{17}' awk -v m=1 -v p=17 '
    BEGIN { re = ENVIRON["RE"] }
    { c = substr($0,m,p) } 
    c ~ "^(" re ")$" '"$r"' { N++ }
    END { print N+0 }
' file
1
```

If you have to write `&& substr($0,28,2)=="06"` somewhere though, then it's not at all obvious why you wouldn't just write it in the awk script instead of in a shell variable - whatever you're trying to do, there's got to be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk ... r='&& substr($0,28,2)==06'
    '... c ~ "^(" re ")$" r  { ... } '
```

This looks like you're trying to use an awk variable to build the condition on the fly? That is, to use the contents of the awk variable `r` as part of awk syntax.

I don't think that can work. In awk, back to back values are taken as string concatenation, so that turns into something like `c ~ "^(" re ")$&& substr($0,28,2)==06"`, i.e. it would take the contents of `r` as part of the regex to match against.

E.g. `awk -v var=bar  '$0 ~ "foo" var'` would print lines containing `foobar`, and it works similarly even if the variable contains `&&` or such.

It probably won't work anywhere near that in any other programming language either, since separation between code and data is pretty much a requirement for sane and safe programs. It doesn't work like that even in the shell. (Without `eval` or such.)

Just write the whole expression out in full.

Answer (score 2):

With some changes you can get it to output expected results:

```
RE='[^[:space:]]' awk -v m=1 -v p=17 \
$'(r=substr($0,28,2)=="06")&&
(substr($0,m,p) !~ re) {N++}
BEGIN {re = ENVIRON["RE"]}
END {print N+0}' < input_file.txt
```

Edits:-

- Convert the awk variable r declared on the commandline to be inside the `$'...'` code block.
- Remove the `&&`, turning it to a boolean.
- stick the `&&` between the `c ~ ...` and `r` boolean conditions.
- Change the numeric comparison `==06` to a string comparison `=="06"`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you can use the `FIELDWIDTHS` variable to specify the widths of fixed width fields:

```
gawk '($1!~/[^ ]/) && ($3=="06"){++c} END{print c+0}' FIELDWIDTHS='17 10 2 *' file
```

You could try to parameterise the awk script – some attempts at that:

```
str=06 gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='17 10 2 *' '
  ($1 !~ /[^ ]/) && ($3"" == ENVIRON["str"]) {
      ++c
  }
  END {print c+0}
' file
```

```
str=06 rexp='^ {17}$' gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='17 10 2 *' -v rexp_col=1 -v str_col=3 '
  ($rexp_col ~ ENVIRON["rexp"]) && ($str_col"" == ENVIRON["str"]) {
      ++c
  }
  END {print c+0}
' file
```